# how to resize only the height of responsive image?

Tags: css, html

**making the image on mobile device longer!**
i have a image ( the header of the website) when i resize the window into mobile format it resize the image . but i want the height of the image (header) longer!

is it possible?

```
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

but that doesn't make the job it make it scale the width and also the height '
i need the height longer.

when i scale it on mobile device the header image of the website should be longer

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this? you can set a custom height (i.e. 300px) that will not change for any window width

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

in CSS

```
.image { background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/25/14/12/nature-3106213_960_720.jpg') no-repeat center center; width:100%; height:300px; background-size:cover; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If that image is background image you can set padding to the header section and adjust to values to your needs. You can then target media queries for mobiles.

```
#header {
     padding:300px 0;
}
```